# POJOs to byte array vs POJOs to json

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm a newbie at Java. I'm just confusing about serialization and deserialization.
So, I'm confusing that which one I should use. 
I'm looking a round and found that Boon, Jackson, GSON (I'm currently using GSON, but some of article using Jackson and Boon) for JSON serialization. And serialize object into byte array or binary object.
Just, which one was faster and which one I should chose?
I'm make this for my simple application, saving current state, document and some other thing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If performance isn't important (and I guess in your case it is not) I recommend you to go with a human readable format.

Comment: @MyGGaN: in case of perfomance, which one I should chose? I'm currently using ByteArrayBuffer (the next day may be apache.common :D) to serialize POJOs to byte arrays. (I'm passing byte via thrift). So I just think about json in some point. And now I'm stuck with JSON vs Base64 vs byte array. It's too complicate now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serialize data means convert them to a sequence of bytes.

This sequence can be interpreted as a sequence of readable chars as happens in json, xml, yaml and so on.

The same sequence can be also a sequence of binary data that is not human readable.

There are pro and cons for each serialization approach.

Pro of human readable:

- Many existing libraries to serialize deserialize data
- The data can be easily debugged
- Many existing libraries and apis use this solution

Cons:

- Many bytes needed
- Serialization and deserialization process can be difficult and time machine consuming

Pro and cons of binary data:

Pro:

- Faster serialization deserialization process
- Less data to transfer over the network

Cons:

- Difficult to read the data that are passed over the network
- Not only one representation of same data (BigEndian or not for example)

Comment: I have solved my problem, but this one is the correct answer I have found. Thanks :)